# Button that starts an evaluation which is monitored with a progress indicator

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, monitoring

I have a `DynamicModule` in which I which I wish to start an operation (actually import files) with a button. I would like to monitor the progress with a ProgressIndicator but can't get it to work. This simple example works:

```
Monitor[
Table[Pause[0.1]; n, {n, 1, 100}],
Dynamic[ProgressIndicator[n, {1, 100}]]
];
```

I find it interesting that it works even with the final semi-colon. In a  `DynamicModule` this  also works:

```
ClearAll[test];
test[] := DynamicModule[{},
 Row[{Monitor[
   Table[Pause[0.1]; n, {n, 1, 100}],
  Dynamic[ProgressIndicator[n, {1, 100}]]
  ];}]
  ]

test[]
```

Now I try to put in a button to start and I am lost

```
ClearAll[test1];
test1[] := DynamicModule[{},
  Row[{Button["Start", Monitor[
   Table[Pause[0.1]; n, {n, 1, 100}],
   Dynamic[ProgressIndicator[n, {1, 100}]]
   ];]}]
  ]   

test1[]
```

I have tried several alternatives with no success. I would like the progress indicator to appear in the same row as the button once it has been pressed.

Comment: I do not understand what you are doing, but try Method -> "Queued" on the Button and see if this helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With small modifications of the [code provided by m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77496/18476) you can get the `Button` and the `ProgressIndicator` in the same `Row`. However, it is always there now and will not appear and disappear.

```
DynamicModule[{n = 1}, 
 Row[{Button["Start", n = 1;
  Do[Pause[0.1]; ++n, {i, 1, 100}], Method -> "Queued"], Spacer[23],
  Dynamic[ProgressIndicator[n, {1, 100}]]}]]
```

[image: output]

In order to get an appearing and disappearing `ProgressIndicator` you can use

```
DynamicModule[{n = 0}, 
  Row[{Button["Start", n = 1;
    Do[Pause[0.1]; ++n, {i, 1, 100}], Method -> "Queued"], Spacer[23],
    Dynamic@If[n == 0 || n == 101, "", ProgressIndicator[n, {1, 100}]]}]]
```

[image: gif]

Comment: Many thanks for this  it works well. Most helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The closest I can get to what you ask for is

```
DynamicModule[{n},
  Button["Start",
    n = 0;
    Monitor[Do[Pause[0.1]; ++n, {i, 1, 100}], 
      Dynamic[ProgressIndicator[n, {1, 100}]]],
    Method -> "Queued"]]
```

which, after the button is clicked on, produces

[image: progress]

The progress indicator appears in its own temporary cell, not in a row with the button. This is how [`Monitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Monitor.html) behaves, and I don't know how to change that behavior.

Comment: Thanks -it works. As you say it appears in a temporary cell. Perhaps I will have to give up my hope of having it in the same row as the button. However significant progress from where I was which is good.