# Activity indicators for slow Dynamic expressions?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, gui-construction, monitoring, asynchronous-processing

With `Dynamic` and gui-constructs like `Popup` I always have a problem: 
***when an expression takes a while to evaluate the Dynamic parts look bad and usually breaks.*** For example, imagine a PopupMenu showing choices whose data has yet to be downloaded. I tried using things like `PrintTemporary` but they didn't achieve the in-place effect I'm looking for.

*So, for an arbitrarily long running dynamic, inserting **Activity Indicators** (looped animations) seamlessly is what I'm after.*

Here's my first attempt:

[image]

and the code:

```
assnMenu[f_,a_Association, title_:"Choose"] := Module[
        {am,b,r,g},
        blup=Style[Pane[Magnify[ProgressIndicator[Appearance->"Percolate"],2]
            ,Alignment->Center],Background->Transparent];
        r=blup;
        g:=(r=blup;r=f[#])&;
        onValueChange[b, g];
        am = Table[With[{i=i}, a[i]:>(b=i)], {i, Keys@a}];
        b = First @ Keys[a];
        Panel @ Grid[
            {{ActionMenu[title, am, Method->"Queued"], 
                Dynamic[Style[a[b],FontFamily->"Arial Black",FontSize->14],UpdateInterval->1]},
            {Dynamic[r, TrackedSymbols:>{r}],SpanFromLeft}},
            Alignment->{Center,Center}
        ]
    ]

onValueChange[a_,f_] := Module[{},
        a/:Set[a,x_]:=((OwnValues[a]={HoldPattern[a]:>x}; f[x]);a)
    ]
```

This almost achieves what I want, but has a few glitches:

- This seems too complicated to be the right way to do this.
- In the current form `assnMenu[slowFunc, <|10 -> "A", 5 -> "B"|>]` takes 10 seconds to evaluate, so there is leakage.
- I couldn't get it to work with a `DynamicModule`, (which has the nice option `DynamicEvaluationTimeouts`), which would help a lot.
- I probably overlooked some part of the docs, I feel like there should already be high level functionalities handling this sort of stuff.

Comment: Do you think it is a duplicate? [Palette button with progress bar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78014/5478)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An adaption of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77524/18476) for an `ActionMenu` and to your styling:

```
assnMenuK[slowF_, a_Association, title_: "Choose"] := 
 DynamicModule[{done = False, lastSelection = ""},
  Grid[{{
     ActionMenu[title,
      KeyValueMap[#2 :> (lastSelection = #2; done = "working"; 
          slowF[#1]; done = True) &, a], Method -> "Queued"],
     Dynamic@Style[lastSelection, FontFamily -> "Arial Black", FontSize -> 14]},
    {Dynamic@Switch[done, False, "",
       True, "done", 
       "working", ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Percolate"]], 
     SpanFromLeft}}]]
```

Example:

```
assnMenuK[Pause, <|1 -> "A", 2 -> "B"|>]
```

[image: example]

---

The "in-place effect" can be improved even further, e.g., by using `Invisible["A"]` instead of `""` and `PaneSelector` instead of `Switch`.

```
assnMenuK2[slowF_, a_Association, title_: "Choose"] := DynamicModule[
  {done = False, lastSelection = Invisible["A"]},
  Panel@Grid[{
     {ActionMenu[title,
       KeyValueMap[#2 :> (lastSelection = #2; done = "working";
           slowF[#1]; done = True) &, a]
       , Method -> "Queued"], 
      Dynamic@Style[lastSelection, FontFamily -> "Arial Black", FontSize -> 14]}, 
     {PaneSelector[
        {False -> "",
         True -> "done",
         "working" -> ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Percolate"]},
        Dynamic@Setting@done
        , Alignment -> Center],
      SpanFromLeft}}]]

assnMenuK2[Pause, <|1 -> "A", 2 -> "B"|>]
```

[image: example2]

Comment: The Dynamic in Dynamic[ProgressIndicator[...]] is not needed.

Comment: @ArielSepulveda Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Interesting use of "Setting" in Dynamic@Setting@done . Any comments on why it is needed? I tried replacing it with a FinishDynamic[] after done = "working" and didn't work.

Comment: Setting[] is a mystery to me. I searched in Mathematica files and found 1529 matches for: Setting[#, {0}]&. So it also takes a second, undocumented argument.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino `Dynamic@Setting@done` is just a workaround for [a bug](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100828/18476). I simply prefer it over using `Dynamic@First@{done}`.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino the second argument for `Setting` is undocumented and is even highlighted as a syntax error in the notebook, but it is a level specification.

Comment: Thanks. It was quite important to learn about that bug. I think prefer using Dynamic@Refresh@done