# Dynamic evaluation of Histogram

Tags: dynamic, evaluation, histograms

Can someone explain the following behavior exhibited by a combination of  `SetDelayed`, `Dynamic` and `Histogram`.

Take

```
example := RandomReal[{0, 100}, 100]
```

and compare

```
Dynamic@Histogram[example]
```

[image: static histogram]

with

```
Dynamic@Histogram[{example}]
```

[image: moving histogram]

---

**Use case:**

I would have expected `Histogram` to behave similar to e.g. `ListPlot` i.e. compare

```
Dynamic@ListPlot[{example, example}]
```

[image: ListPlot]

and

```
Dynamic@Histogram[{example, example}]
```

[image]

---

Since Kuba noted in a comment that he can reproduce this behavior in version 10.4 but not 11: I am using Mathematica 11.0.0.0 on OS X 10.11.6

Comment: As @JacobAkkerboom noted in chat, [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100828/4330) might be related

Comment: I believe it was asked before, can't find it. Can reproduce it in 10.4, can not in 11.

Comment: @Kuba I though that this must have been asked before because it is so basic but I couldn't find anything either

Comment: I can confirm the same behaviour in version 11.0.1 on OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: Also compare `Dynamic@{Histogram[example]; First@example}` and `Dynamic@{Histogram[{example}]; First@example}`.