# Dynamic not responding to Refresh TrackedSymbols

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I am attempting to creating a UI dialogue that updates itself as selections are made.  The issue is the UI is not updating itself even though the dependent variables are being updated.  A *very minimal* example follows.

```
v =.;
Panel[
 Column@{
   Row[{"Pick", 
     CheckboxBar[Dynamic@v, # -> IntegerName@# & /@ Range[3]]}],
   Dynamic[
    Refresh[
     If[ValueQ[v],
      v + 1,
      "Pick something"
      ],
     TrackedSymbols :> {v}
     ]
    ]}
 ]
```

What I am expecting to happen is that once `v` is assigned a value that the `If` will update to show the calculation.  However, `v` is updated but the `Dynamic` does not update.

In the actual case the user select a value from a `PopupMenu`.  This value is used to query a database with the resultset being used in the next `PopupMenu`. Similar to the above except there are some function calls. The variable `v` must initially be clear.

Ideas?

---

**Update**

I had some to and fro emails with WRI and I think they are looking into why ValueQ does not re-evaluate in the `If`.  I have worked out that I can use `v = Null;` to start and `v =!= Null` in the `If` to get things to work as expected.

Comment: The expression is refreshing fine, as you can see by using `If[v, v + 1, "Pick something"]` instead of your `If` statement. It's the `ValueQ` that is not behaving as you expected. I wonder if the fact that `CheckboxBar` always returns a list is getting in the way.

Comment: @Kuba I have reported to WRI. Ugh, it is going to be one of those weeks, me'thinks.

Comment: @Kuba In the actual I am testing an integer variable so I think I have to go with `ValueQ` unless there is another way to test if an integer variable as a value.

Comment: @Edmund `IntegerQ`?

Answer (score 2):

I also think this is a bug along the lines of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100828/169) one. There are obviously certain cases where the tracking dependencies are not resolved correctly. Usually there are simple things you can change in your code to get the code working as intended anyway, but unfortunately no simple pattern which always works well. Here I would suggest something like this:

```
v =.;
Panel[
  Column[{
    Row[{
      "Pick", 
      CheckboxBar[Dynamic@v, # -> IntegerName@# & /@ Range[3]]
    }],
    Dynamic[
      Refresh[
        v;
        If[ValueQ[v],
          v + 1,
          "Pick something"
        ],
        TrackedSymbols :> {v}
      ]
    ]
  }]
]
```

Of course that is just a workaround, but that is probably all you can expect in this case...

Comment: fyi, my guess is that the problems like this appear when MMA tries to optimize things and assumes that the FrontEnd can handle things, which it can't. So here `If` is present also in ``FEPrivate` `` context but somone forgot to check the content.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a comment with code. I am confused as to the exact part of the code that is not refreshing.

It seems to me that the complication may arise from the use of `ValueQ` on the output of `CheckboxBar`, which is not a symbol, but a list.

Consider the following variation on Edmund's code, in which

- instead of `CheckboxBar` (which returns a list) I am using `SetterBar` (which returns a single value);
- instead of a string value, I assign to `v` a True / False value;
- instead of checking whether `v` has a value with ValueQ, I simply use the dynamically updated value.

  ```
  v =.;
  Panel[
   Column@{
     Row[{"Pick", SetterBar[Dynamic@v, {False, True}]}], 
     Dynamic[Refresh[If[v, "True was selected", "Pick something"], TrackedSymbols :> {v}]]
     }
   ]
  ```

Initially, this evaluates to:

[image: false]

After selecting `True`, this changes to:

[image: True]

In fact, this works even without the `Refresh`:

```
v =.;
Panel[
 Column@{
   Row[{"Pick", SetterBar[Dynamic@v, {False, True}]}], 
   Dynamic[If[v, "True was selected", "Pick something"]]
  }
]
```

[image: False - no refresh]
[image: True - no refresh]