# Module vs. DynamicModule wrt ProgressIndicator

Tags: bugs, dynamic

Why does the following work for `Module` but not `DynamicModule`?

```
Module[{test}, 
  test = 0;
  Column[{Button["Calc", 
            test = 0.1; Pause[1.0]; 
            test = 0.25; Pause[1.0]; 
            test = 0.5; Pause[1.0]; 
            test = 0.75; Pause[1.0]; 
            test = 0.9; Pause[1.0]; 
            test = 1.0, Method -> "Queued"], 
  Row[{"Progress: ", ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[test]]}]}]]
```

[image]

```
DynamicModule[{test}, 
  test = 0;
  Column[{Button["Calc", 
            test = 0.1; Pause[1.0]; 
            test = 0.25; Pause[1.0]; 
            test = 0.5; Pause[1.0]; 
            test = 0.75; Pause[1.0]; 
            test = 0.9; Pause[1.0]; 
            test = 1.0, Method -> "Queued"], 
  Row[{"Progress: ", ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[test]]}]}]]
```

[image]

If I have other reasons to need the module to be a `DynamicModule`, how can I get this functionality to work?

Comment: Because of the most annoying bug in UI: [100828](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100828/5478), your example is even worse to find a fix for.

Comment: In this case `Refresh` works.

Comment: Wow. Yes, that is an annoying bug, @Kuba! And thank you @chuy, that does indeed work beautifully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @chuy, we have a solution:

```
DynamicModule[{test}, 
  test = 0;
  Column[{Button["Calc", 
            test = 0.1; Pause[1.0]; 
            test = 0.25; Pause[1.0]; 
            test = 0.5; Pause[1.0]; 
            test = 0.75; Pause[1.0]; 
            test = 0.9; Pause[1.0]; 
            test = 1.0, Method -> "Queued"], 
  Row[{"Progress: ", 
       ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[Refresh[test]]]}]}]]
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `TrackedSymbols` option.

Comment: Ah, thank you! This is my first time to use Refresh, so I didn't even think to leave it out. I'll fix the answer.